# Need help updating many data tables: value shown when table is called after update is no the same as the value updated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

In my app I have to validate all of an order and its content.

An order base is shaped like this:

```
public class OrderInfo
{
    public int Order_ID { get; set; }

    (...)

    public List<OrderDetailInfo> ListOrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

All the other fields are simple fields like a billing adress, the order total, and so on.

To link these order Details to an order, here's the Order Detail class:

```
public class OrderDetailInfo
{
    public int OrderDetail_ID { get; set; }
    public int Order_ID { get; set; }
    public int InventoryID { get; set; }
    public int OrderDetailQuantity { get; set; }

    public OrderInfo Order { get; set; }
    public InventoryInfo Inventory { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, an Order Detail is also linked to an inventory item. Thus passing an order to buy or sell items will increase / decrease its quantity.

Well, since we're at it, here's the InventoryInfo class:

```
public class InventoryInfo
{
    public int Inventory_ID { get; set; }

    public int  Object_ID { get; set; }

    public ObjectInfo Object { get; set; }

    public int  Inventory_Nb_In_Stock { get; set; }
    (...)
}
```

So, based on all three classes, I have this method which needs to validate the content of an order and update the quantity of each items related to an order detail.

Here's how I proceed:

```
internal void ValidateSupplierOrder(OrderInfo _order, List<OrderDetailInfo> _listOldOrderDetails)
{
    var orderQry = from o in mDb.OrderInfo
               where o.Order_ID  == _order.Order_ID 
               select o;

    OrderInfo originalOrder = orderQry.Single();

    foreach (var orderDetailInfo in _order.ListOrderDetails )
    {
        mDb.OrderDetailInfo.Add(orderDetailInfo);

        mDb.SaveChanges();
    }

    foreach (var orderDetailInfo in _order.mListOrderDetail)
    {
        OrderDetailInfo info = orderDetailInfo;

        var inventoryQry = from i in mDb.InventoryInfo
                           where i.Inventory_ID  == info.Inventory_ID 
                           select i;

        InventoryInfo originalItem = inventoryQry.Single();

        InventoryInfo itemToModify = originalItem;

        itemToModify.Inventory_Nb_In_Stock  += orderDetailInfo.OrderDetailQuantity;

        mDb.Entry(originalItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(itemToModify);

        mDb.SaveChanges();
    }

    mDb.Entry(originalOrder).CurrentValues.SetValues(orderToModify);

    mDb.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now if I look in the database tables while the process goes on (and with debuggin mode), the values are updated **correctly**.

But now when I load the same item that got updated using this method in another part of the app, the `Inventory_Nb_In_Stock` fields show the value **as it was before it was updated**. So if I have 5 `Blue Pens`, and I pass an order of 4, my data table shows that I have 9 `Blue Pens`, but when I check through the app how many `Blue Pens` I have, it says **5**. Can anybody check my validate, am I updating too many values at the same times? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I have made a few tests and it seems like the value is updated only after I rebuild the app.

Comment: I would bet on a caching problem. Have you tried to deactivate the caching on your pages ?

Comment: To be fairly honest, I never even bothered about caching data, nor did I checked that. How can I do that?

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using ?

Comment: My app is build with MVC 4.

Answer (score 0):

Ressources about MVC 4 Caching :  http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/4R5c050113-Understanding-Caching-in-Asp.Net-MVC-with-example.html

In my app, which was strongly tied to the database (also mvc3), I needed that no page was cached at all, so instead of decorating every method, I changed the `Global.asax.cs` to add this :

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I will try this. When and where do you call this method?

Comment: This is called automatically on all requests: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx (Lifecycle events and the Global.ASAX)

Comment: Seems like it does not work. I have tried to put a breakpoint at this method, but it does not seem to be called. Moreover, after testing the whole lot, the values remains the same.